# Convert WPF application to DLL

Tags: wpf, winforms, dll, integration

I have a WPF application which I need to integrate with WinForms. As suggested in some forum, I removed window1.xaml and app.xaml from my project and then changed the project type to class library. After that, when I add the DLL reference in my WinForms project I get an error 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' 
What is the reason for this?

Also since I use resource dictionary, I was adding all resource dictionary references inside merge dictionary in my app.xaml. Now only with user control how would I do this??

Also one more exception that I observed is 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.'

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i converted my wpf app to DLL by removing app.xaml and window.
Make sure that if you are using ResourceDictionary files then each user control should have a reference to it as merged dictionary and since each such reference is local to its own user control if there are nested user controls i.e, user control in a user control all user controls should have a reference to resource dictionary files.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a complex process, involving a lot of refactoring and code extraction.

What you should be doing is adding some separate projects to your visual studio solution - and moving all your reusable logic to a Class Library project. You will need to adjust namespaces, and such... but all your reusable code should go there.

Your WPF application should then reference the Class Library project and you can continue to use it... the difference is now you can have a Win Forms project in the solution that ALSO uses the class library...

in effect you are extracting your domain code out of the UI as much as possible... you could potentially write a web app then that would consume the same library...